# php mongodb delete item from mongodb array field

Tags: php, mongodb, substring

I am using php to delete an item from a mongodb array field called "bought". This is how my document is formatted :

[image]

Let's say I want to delete the item with `"itemID":16` and I give as input the correct id and as date of purchase : `"Tue Feb 02 2021 19:25"`  which is a substring of  `"Tue Feb 02 2021 19:25:03 GMT+200 ... "`

I want to simultaneously check if the id is found and my input date is a substring of the item date . If both conditions are met delete the item :

My code :

```
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
  $db = $m ->ECommerce;
  $userCollection = $db->users;

  $cursor = $userCollection->find(['userName'=>$_POST['userName']]);

  foreach($cursor as $usr){
    foreach($usr["bought"] as $buy){
      $itemFound = $buy["itemID"] == (int)$_POST['itemID'] && strpos($buy["dateOfPurchase"],$_POST['itemDate'])!==false;
      if($itemFound==true){ //succesfully checks the condition but does not delete the item 
        $userCollection->updateOne( 
          array("userName" => $_POST['userName']),
          array( '$pull' => 
              array(
                  "bought" => array(
                      "itemID" => (int)$_POST['itemID'],
                      "dateOfPurchase"=> strpos($buy["dateOfPurchase"],$_POST['itemDate'])==true
                  )
              )
          )
        );
        echo "Item has been deleted";
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
```

So my problem is how to query mongodb to delete an item from a document's array if I have a substring of the array field and the correct id

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution and a relatively simple one .

```
foreach($cursor as $usr){
    foreach($usr["bought"] as $buy){
      if(strpos($buy['dateOfPurchase'], $_POST['itemDate'])!==false && $buy["itemID"] == (int)$_POST["itemID"] ){
         //enters 
         $userCollection->updateOne(
          array("userName"=> $_POST['userName']),
          array( '$pull' => 
            array(
                  "bought" => $buy //item as reference 
                )
            )
          );
          echo "Item has been deleted";
          exit();    
      }

    }
  }
```

without writing a giant query just reference the item you want to delete `($buy)`